# How to integrate google ratings option in android application?

Tags: android, google-ranking

How to integrate google ratings option in android application?

I want to add rating bar using google api..

Please can anyone help out..

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate Google ratings"? Just add a way to go to the rate page?

Comment: I want to add rating bar in android app using google api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "RatingBar" widget in android....

Comment: when user going to give rating to any product or website link that time it need to ask Google authentication(username and password)

Comment: then Integrate Google+ in your app n check while user rating to any product is Session valid.. refer https://developers.google.com/+/